# Serviço no JBoss não faz log e não funciona direito

Tags: java, spring, jboss

Eu tenho um serviço que está deployado dentro do meu JBoss EAP 6.4, quando eu tento  acessar os end-points do serviço é retornado uma reposta padão, junto com o status 500, porém nada é logado no console e eu também não consigo debugar as rota pois não para em nenhum breakpoint, é como se não estivesse batendo nas rotas do serviço disponibilizado.

Quando eu fui ver o log do serviço, dentro de `C:\opt\EAP-6.4.0\standalone\log\myapp`, ele mostra o seguinte erro ao acessar qualquer end-point:

```
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.NotFoundException: RESTEASY001185: Could not find resource for relative : /v1/canais/default/validacao of full path: http://localhost:8080/myapp/v1/canais/default/validacao
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootSegment.matchChildren(RootSegment.java:361) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:na]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootSegment.matchRoot(RootSegment.java:375) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:na]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootSegment.matchRoot(RootSegment.java:368) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:na]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.getResourceInvoker(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:349) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:na]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getInvoker(SynchronousDispatcher.java:191) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:na]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:124) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:na]
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:na]
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:na]
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:na]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar!/:1.0.2.Final-redhat-2]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:178) [spring-orm-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar!/:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar!/:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar!/:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:150) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:854) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]
```

Alguém sabe o que pode estar causando isso?

Comment: Provavelmente é algum problema de configuração no web.xml

Answer (score 0):

Adicione isso no seu web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/myapp</param-value>
</context-param>
```